# Eclipse JBoss hybrid Mobile tools + cordovasim shows deprecated

Tags: eclipse, cordova, jboss, eclipse-plugin

Today I am trying to install the JBoss Hybrid mobile tools + Cordovasim in my eclipse IDE but it is showing Deprecated in the headings.

Does anyone know why it is deprecated and alternative for this. Thanks!

[Jboss Cordova eclipse Deprecated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7PuC.jpg)

Comment: I am getting following error while installing the plugin -

Comment: Problems occurred while performing installation: The following connectors are not available: JBoss Hybrid Mobile Tools + CordovaSim (Deprecated) (id=org.jboss.tools.aerogear.easymport.feature.feature.group, org.jboss.tools.aerogear.thym.feature.feature.group, org.jboss.tools.cordovasim.feature.feature.group, org.jboss.tools.browsersim.feature.feature.group, org.jboss.tools.livereload.feature.feature.group, org.jboss.tools.jst.angularjs.feature.feature.group, org.jboss.tools.feedhenry.feature.group, site=https://devstudio.redhat.com/11/stable/updates/)